# Vue state not updated with default injected value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

If you click the button, you can see the value of `state` updated in the console, but it isn't updated in the page output. How can I make it work with a default injected value?

```js
const Component = {
  inject: {
    state: {
      default: () => ({
        example: 1
      })
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <div>{{ state }}</div>
    <button @click="click">click</button>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.state.example += 1
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Component
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component></component>
</div>
```

Is it related to as Vue docs say "Note: the provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive. This is intentional. However, if you pass down an observed object, properties on that object do remain reactive."? I'm confused about the difference between the BINDINGS not being reactive but the OBSERVED OBJECT being reactive. Could you show an example to demo the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it is not clear what you want - where's the **provider** for the "injection"? Why do you use **inject** in the same component as you use the value itself?

Here's your code, without **inject**:

#### 1. Use the **data** attribute

```js
const Component = {
  data() {
    return {
      state: {
        example: 1
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <div>{{ state }}</div>
    <button @click="click">click</button>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.state.example += 1
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Component
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component></component>
</div>
```

Just use the **data** attribute - you can have a default value for `example`.

#### 2. Use **inject**ion

**inject** is something completely different - it's a way to pass values from a **provider** to a **consumer**:

```js
const Component = {
  inject: ['state1'],
  data() {
    return {
      state: {
        example: 1
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <div>injected: {{ state1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ state }}</div>
    <button @click="click">click</button>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.state.example += 1
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  provide: {
    state1: {
      example1: 1
    }
  },
  components: {
    Component
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component></component>
</div>
```

You can "skip" levels of components and use the **provided** value in components where you **inject** it - you don't have to pass it all the way down as **props**.

#### 3. Create reactive **inect**ion

If you want to have reactive **injection** then you need to pass down something more complex:

```js
const Component1 = {
  inject: ['state2'],
  data() {
    return {
      state: {
        example: 1
      }
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <div>injected: {{ state2.state2P }}</div>
    <div>{{ state }}</div>
    <button @click="click">click</button>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.state.example += 1
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      state2: {
        example2: 1
      }
    }
  },
  provide() {
    // create an object (state2)
    const state2 = {}
    // define a property on the object (state2P), that
    // has a get() function that always gets the provider's
    // value you want to inject
    Object.defineProperty(state2, 'state2P', {
      enumerable: true,
      get: () => this.state2,
    })
    // return the created object (with a property that always
    // gets the value in the parent)
    return {
      state2
    }
  },
  components: {
    Component1
  },
  methods: {
    parentClick() {
      this.state2.example2 += 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component1></component1>
  <button @click="parentClick">PARENT CLICK</button>
</div>
```

I added a button to the template, so you can see that a `method` defined in the provider component's scope changes the value displayed in the consumer component's scope. (Also had to change the component's name, as Vue started to "whine" about using a restricted word.)